# A little calendar icon to show when something was posted?

Tags: 7, datetime

I seem to recall trying a theme - I forget which; maybe Marinelli? - where each post on the from page had a nice little calnedar icon with the day and month of the pst.

Is that a module which I can use on other themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple theme modification, probably also easily done via .css. There is not need for a module for this.

Simply edit your themes node.tpl.php page in your theme directory/templates/

Find:

```
 <?php print $submitted; ?>
```

Wrap a simple tag round it like so:

```
      <span class="date_submitted"><?php print $submitted; ?></span>
```

Write your css:

```
.date_submitted {
  background: url("../img/icons/calendar_view_month.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent; 
}
```

You have to save the calendar image or create your own -> [image: Calendar Image]

You also probably need to do some simple formatting in the css like padding-left (to push the text to the right to stop it overlaying the image) etc ...

If you don't know what I am on about, read up about css3 and drupal themeing and learn some basics.

Comment: +1 and the answer, thanks. I reckon I can handle that. What I need to read up on is how to prevent my mods being overwritten if the theme is ever updated.